# What is this word referring to in Bhutochatanam?

Tags: translation-request, sanskrit, sandhyavandanam, meaning, ghosts

This sloka is used before puja (Sandhyavandanam in my case) to clear away ghosts and other bad spirits.

```
उत्तिष्ठन्तु भूतपिशाचा येते भूमि भारका |
एतेषां अविरोधेन ब्रह्म कर्म समारभे   ||
```

This can be translated as follows:

> Let the ghosts and demons who are the burden of the earth rise.
>
> Without contradiction to **these**, I commence the Brahman action

My question is, what does the word '**एतेषां (these)**' refer to? Does it refer to the bhootas pishachas or is my translation of the second line wrong?

Comment: उत्तिष्ठन्तु can mean both rise up (become visible) or leave off (get destroyed) but in this case it should be the 2nd one prd and एतेषां can mean them, their, these. So, i think the correct translation should be. *"Let the ghosts and demons who are the burden of the earth **go away or get destroyed** so that i can start brahma karma (puja path) without **their** distractions."* I hope this clarifies your queries. ..

Comment: This not vaidik mantra there is another mantra which is given vama dev rishi it commands to buthas to obey lord shiva command that they should not distriub brahmana karma. they goaway according lord shivas command. if this mantra uttered with chandas and meaning with correct swara ..no bhoota will come near the person for sure

Comment: @Savdy Please post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @PrasannaR I don't know any other ones and everyone here uses this only.

Comment: @xax ok. ..

Comment: Mantra is called bhoothashttanam of aphasthambha sutra one cannot give mantra just like that is why I'm not answering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

उत्तिष्ठन्तु can mean both rise up (become visible) or leave off (get destroyed) but in this case it should be the 2nd one prd and एतेषां can mean them, their, these. So, i think the correct translation should be.:->

> *"Let the ghosts and demons who are the burden of the earth **go away (get destroyed),** so that i can start brahma karma (puja path) without **their** distractions."*

I hope this clarifies your queries. ..